# use of ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

I know basic use of '?' ternary operator. window.URL should be expression, which should return true or false. But in this case, it is returning a string.

how this expression is evaluated.

```
var createSrc = window.URL ? window.URL.createObjectURL : function(stream) {return stream;};
```

Comment: Ternary operator work like this:

test?expressionIfTrue:expressionIfFalse. What is the test you want to perform on on window.URL ?

Comment: But `window.URL` is not an expression which give you `true` or `false`. It's an object and thus will always be "true".

Comment: Also can you please clarify what you mean by "it is returning a string". *What* is returning a string? What is that strings value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is evaluated to `true` as long it is not empty, in which case it is `false`.

Though it doesn't look like `window.URL` is a string in this case. It appears to be an object, which if `undefined` will evaluate to `false` as well.

What your statement does, is it checks if `window.URL` exists. If it does, then it will assign to `createSrc`, the value of `window.URL.createObjectURL`, which I assume is probably a function. Otherwise, it will assign the third part of the ternary operator, `function(stream) {return stream;}`.

This means, `createSrc` should always be a function and calling it will not generate an error.